# how to get items from mysql database added to the page with a checkbox for each item?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, checkbox

I need to write a function that does two things. It pulls a query from a mysql database and for each row found display the items of that row (There are 5 fields in the table id, title, description, timestamp, and a boolean). For each item displayed I need to have a checkbox displayed that if a user clicks the boolean is changed from off to on.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code, as we don't know they layout of your database? Plus I'm sure no one wants to do all your work for you :)

Comment: I have tried a jquery script that iterates through the database and pulls things into a checkbox. I just run into an issue with having additional fields associated with the array. The jquery looks similar to this...http://jsfiddle.net/2KJ7w/1/. Although mine pulls from mysql instead of an associative array from a where loop. I am looking for more php since I think that would work better.

Comment: I know how to pull from the db.... I don't know how to add a checkbox for each item...I pull from the db with a where loop but I think I need a for loop since for each row I need to add a checkbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take this with a pinch of salt, I have not gone into any sort of security, and I'm sure there are much nicer ways but in the short time I had this might help you make a start.

```
<?php

$query = " SELECT id, title, description, timestamp, checkbox FROM database WHERE x = y";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

echo '<form action="">';
while ($row = $continent_results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $id             =$row['id'];
    $title          =$row['title'];
    $description    =$row['description'];
    $timestamp      =$row['timestamp'];
    $checkBox       =$row['checkBox'];

    echo 'ID: ', $id;
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Title: ', $title;
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Desc: ', $description;
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Time: ', $timestamp;
    echo '<br>';
    if (checkbox == true){
        echo 'Check <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="$id" checked="checked">';
    }else{
        echo 'Check <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="$id">';
    }
}
echo '</form>';

?>
```